# When to check Google Play Services in your app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm building an app that uses the Google Maps. I'm following the official guide from Google and went to this link: 
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Question:
Do I need to include checking for the availability of the Google Play Services for the map?

It's quite vague, it does not say which APIs requires this checking.
Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

In general, using the new pattern for accessing Google Play services APIs (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client), you do not need to pre-check for availability as `GoogleApi` handles the connection and availability updates on behalf of your app, including those situations requiring user interaction.

Even using the older [`GoogleApiClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-api-client), you can auto-manage the connection and error resolutions with `.enableAutoManage(...)`.